# How to add RegexKitLite framework?

Tags: iphone, frameworks

I am new to iphone development.I want to add RegexKitLite framework.I have downloaded  the source file but i am not able to add the framework in my project.Please help me out.Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Add `RegexKitLite.h` and `RegexKitLite.m` into your project.
2. Add the SDK library `libicucore.dylib` into your project.

Answer (score 3):

@KennyTM : you don't have to add `libicucore.dylib` to the project.

You can simply open the project's information panel and add `-licucore` to the other linker flags as shown below to prevent warnings.

[image: Project Information Panel]